# How to store php login session in java how to send the session

Tags: java, codeigniter, apache-httpcomponents

How to store php login session (in this case, codeigniter framework based application) in java and how to send the session when execute HttpResponse.execute(HttpGet) (Apache HttpClient).

For experiment, i've developed a testing application and for login you can access http://sisco.mipropia.com/exp/auth/do_login?username=sisco&password=sisco. To test the session, you can access http://sisco.mipropia.com/exp/item/get_item?item_id=1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want the session to maintain/check whether he is logged in or not right ?

Comment: No, the session is maintained by php application. i need the session for each request from java desktop application

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how codeigniter manages sessions, but most frameworks do it by using cookies. Take a look at this [example](http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/QuickStart) to figure how httpcomponents deals with session cookies.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exatcly, you should use/enable cookies in your http client to make your app store the session.